# Call C# from Android/Java native lib

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Let's assume that we have a binding library created over native AAR lib.
We are consuming this library in Xamarin Android application.

Is it possible to read data e.g. included in application AssemblyInfo from Java side - by native lib from the binding?

Comment: Sure via an `ACW`, provide a callback into C# (actually the generated wrapper (`[Export]`) Java method that Xamarin will create) that you would need to setup via an exposed Java method in your Java lib, or in your Java lib use reflection to find and call the exported Java wrapper method (that in turn calls the actual C# method that returns whatever data you need): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/java.interop.exportattribute?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9

Comment: Thanks. One more similar question - is there a way to direct read EmbeddedResource file from binding lib by native part due to missing Assets build action in binding project.

Comment: EmbeddedResource? Are you talking about a .Net assembly-based resource? If so, it would be far easy to exposed an `ACW` method from C# that returns it to Java|Kotlin. Otherwise you are going to have to load and parse the assembly (binary) to find & extract the resource. Why not just include the "file" as an Android `raw` (or asset) resource and you can load it directly from your Java|Kotlin lib and from C# (if needed) or have your C# code (at startup), extract and save the file in the app's cache directory using a predetermined filename  that your Java library looks for and loads....

Comment: The problem is that the only place that I can embed it is in the binding lib as we are providing one to the customers and we can't force them to add anything in the app. The binding project is lacking Assets build action so we have only EmbeddedResource action to choose.